# Web Application Questions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, client-server

I am having a bit of trouble finding relevant and updated information. A lot of what I find is from 2001/2002, and the majority of it doesn't apply.

Basically, I want to create a server/client application. The server will be run from a single dedicated machine, and I will install the client on numerous other machines (remotes).

What I am not sure on (never used ASP.NET Web Application) is do I need to plan ahead for it, or can it be added on top?

I am assuming I can just create the Server/Client applications in C# NET, then create the ASP.NET Web App later to give a web based front end to the server application. If this is correct, can anyone possibly link me to good resources for this type of information? As I mentioned, everything I have found is either old, or doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I get what you're asking even though it's not that clear.

You're looking to build a cliet/server application initially and later to provide similar functionlaity via a web based application. Correct? If so, then:

To some extent you do need to plan and design for it. This is what I recommended: Let's assume you're using a layered architecture for you server side application and these layers are:
1. TCP/IP Interface layer
2. Business layer
3. Data layer

The business layer and data layer will be reused in your ASP.NET application as well. Both these layers MUST be completely agnostic of and TCP/IP and Http stuff.

The TCP/IP interface layer, sort of translates the TPC/IP ness of your server application to pure C# method calls to normal data types and makes calls into your business layer. If you follow this basic design you will be able to reuse your business layer and data layer.

EDIT

ASP.NET applications are assemblies. They run in the process space of another "application" (worker process) that in turn runs in the process space of IIS. But nonetheless, the architecture I mention in my answer will work for you (I do this all the time) if you're careful about your TCP/IP Interface layer being the barrier (and interface) or in order words decoupling your TCP/IP "ness" from your business layer.

For example, an aspx page (or MVC controller or asp.net handler) is an "Http Interface layer". If used correctly, the "page" handles all of the http/html stuff and "converts" all of the messaging into regular C# method calls on the business layer completely decoupling the business layer from any knowledge of ASP.NET, http, sessions and the like. The business layer in fact should have know knowledge or dependency on anything to do with ASP.NET.

So if your TCP/IP service interface layer performance the same function (that is the sole responsibility of ***Service interface layers***) then you're good to go. And when the time comes, you'll slap on an Http Service interface layer to your system (sharing the BL and DAL). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, what I am confused on is if a ASP Web Application developed in C# NET is an executable with .aspx files just being the front end.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common to have more than one project in an ASP.NET based web site, some of which have really nothing to do with the WEB UI.
A good resource on this will be any beginner's ASP.NET tutorial. (I trust your googling skills :-)).
Just make sure you separate the GUI from the implementation (for example - if you use webForms to test it - make sure you don't rely on any webForms specific implementation).
I really recommend reading a bit about ASP.NET before starting the task, but generally, rest assured your c# projects are "pluggable" to an ASP.NET implementation.
Hope I got the question right..

Comment: Ah, I think that answers my question :) Just to make sure I am understanding correctly...I can write a server console application, then manage it via ASP Web Application without pulling teeth?

Comment: If that is the case I will go ahead and do my server and client applications, then just do a web application later that will provide a management front end for the server.

Comment: You can do that. Just know that everything that has to do anything with the Console, will obviously, be replaced. I suggest you create a different project, call it ConsoleUI, and just send back and forth the data you need, to the rest of your application, keeping in mind that this CosnoleUI will be replaced in the future.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/general/videos

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178093(v=VS.90).aspx

You don't have to create any client application, the client is the web browser.

Comment: I think I am still being a bit confusing. I basically want to have A) A main server application that manages instances of the remote client application B) A main server application that provides a web front end to do the managing of those instances.

Comment: To clarify better, we will say DEDICATED_MACHINE-01 is running the master server application, runs the web application, etc. Then we will have DEDICATED_MACHINE-02 and DEDICATED_MACHINE-03 that are running the remote application. I know that the application that runs on the remote machines isn't going to be a web application (it has no web front end) but the server application that manages these will. So question is, should I do a server.exe, then a web application that interacts with it, or is there some way to make the web application an executable and just handle the server/web app there?

Comment: @Brett, what protocol are you using between your client and server?